# Prepare Debian/Raspian for Power Loss

Tags: debian, power, raspberry-pi, raspbian

My school is in the process of buying two Raspberry Pis for use in the commons to display the news. I'll be creating a startup script to automatically a USB flash drive with a video on it, and to have the video play continuously in a loop. The process should be easy for the person: Unplug Pi, copy file to flash drive, insert flash drive, plug in Pi, profit.

This means that the Pi is going to need to withstand regular power loss. **What can I do to minimize the damage from a power loss on the software side?**

I'm already thinking that mounting the flash drive, /home, /usr, etc. as read only might help. But will that really help?

Comment: Add a [proper shutdown button](http://www.mausberrycircuits.com/) to the Pi, and put the Pi's power supply through a UPS.

Comment: I did a rather elaborate, but effective hack on my system to account for this. I ran a wire from the 5v output on my AC adapter to one of the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi. Then I connected the AC adapter to a battery that outputs 5V to the Raspberry PI. The battery has enough power to run the PI for several hours, but I have a Python script polling the GPIO pin and when it goes low, the Python script shuts down the system safely.

Comment: I'd like to keep the budget as low as possible, TECHIE007. I'll consider it as a worst case scenario option, however. That seems really complex, jbarker2160. :-P I'm looking for something that allows the Pi to shut down quickly without software interaction, however. I would rather not wait for a battery to discharge. :-)

Comment: $17 for the "good" switch on that page -- that's a pretty low cost.

Comment: $17 * 2 Pis = $34... I'm trying to keep the budget as low as possible, and I'm already starting to reach the hard limits of what we have available.